# Linq to XML, find items which are in a specific category

Tags: linq-to-xml, where-clause

I have the following XML-structure (from an external source which isn't very well executed):

```
<items>
 <item>
   <allkindsofinfo></allkindsofinfo>
   <categories>
    <category>
     <name>cat1</name>
    </category>
    <category>
     <name>cat2</name>
    </category>
    <category>
     <name>cat3</name>
    </category>
   </categories>
  </item>
 <item>
  etcetera
```

There are about 150 items which all contain a couple of categories.

Now, using linq, I want to fetch all items which are in a certain category. 
I tried the following in the where-clause:

```
item.Element("categories").Elements("category").Elements("name").ToString().Contains("cat2")
```

This doesn't return any results, even if I know it should.

If I try:

```
item.Element("categories").Element("category").Element("name").ToString().Contains("cat2")
```

it returns results if the categoryname is the first one in the item.

How can I loop through the categorynames of every item to see if it contains a certain string and filter out those items?

Any help is very much appreciated...:-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`where item.Element("categories").Elements("category").Elements("name").Any(n => n.Value = "cat2")` should do if the `name` element value is supposed to be `cat2` exactly. Or use `where item.Element("categories").Elements("category").Elements("name").Any(n => n.Contains("cat2"))` if the name element is supposed to contain "cat2" as a substring.